# NaN result when it shoudn't in java

Tags: java, nan, adaboost

I'm trying to do the AdaBoost algorithm and to obtain the confidence value I used this formula:

```
 Double valorConfianza = (1/2) * (Math.log10(1-tasaErrorMenor/tasaErrorMenor)/Math.log10(2)) ;
```

But it didn't work so I print the values and it gave me this:

```
tasaErrorMenor: 0.121837094
valorConfianza: NaN
```

Why does this happen, if my calculator gives me a normal number?

Comment: I would have expected 0 because `1/2 == 0` (you are doing integer division there).

Comment: Also, `1-tasaErrorMenor/tasaErrorMenor` is 0 because division is done before subtraction. And then you take the `log10` of `0`...

Comment: `(1 / 2.0) * (Math.log10((1 - tasaErrorMenor) / tasaErrorMenor) / Math.log10(2))`, this seems to work, if your intention was to `1 - tasaErrorMenor` first and then divide that by `tasaErrorMenor`.